# Как подключить к приложению AnyCPU (C#) библиотеку x86 (C# или C++)?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Дано:
1. Есть приложение на C#, собранное под AnyCPU, оно подсасывает библиотеки из определенной папки.
2. Одна из библиотек устарела, в ней нужно использовать функции, описанные в библиотеке на c++, которая собрана как x86. 
3. Основное приложение и библиотеку на плюсах переписывать нельзя.
4. Плюсовая библиотека подключается через DLLImport.
5. Винда x64, но в дальнейшей эксплуатации может быть любая

Что пробовал (неудачные попытки):
1. Изменить разрядность библиотеки на c# на x86. Результат: не подключается к программе. Если просто проект новый AnyCPU создать и в ссылках подключить эту библиотеку, то тоже ошибку выдает.
2. Не менять нигде разрядность. Результат: ошибка о невозможности подключить один или несколько модулей, связанных с библиотекой на плюсах.
3. Создать библиотеку на плюсах, скомпилировать под x64, а из нее вызывать x86. Результат: как и в прошлом способе.

Вопрос: как быть-то тут? Как плюсовую библиотеку x86 подключить к шарповскому проекту AnyCPU? Допускаются любые костыли и говнокод, главное чтоб работало.

Comment: Кажется, вы что-то делаете не так.

Comment: Поэтому я задал этот вопрос. Хочется узнать как нужно делать

Comment: очевидно что нужно сменить разрядность приложения

Comment: Приложение трогать нельзя, только библиотеку

Comment: тогда никак не получится

Comment: Сделайте отдельное x86 приложение, которое будет использовать целевую библиотеку, и с которым вы будете взаимодействовать по любому IPC протоколу. Например, сделайте XML-RPC сервер, и взаимодействуйте с ним через потоки ввода-вывода.

Comment: Я бы написал обёртку для плюсовой либы на C++/CLI

Comment: Приложение, зависящее от 32-битной неуправляемой библиотеки никак не может быть AnyCPU. То, что вы хотите, не имеет смысла.